# TortoiseSVN repository browser shows 2 trunks

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm running TortoiseSVN version 1.7.2 (32-bit).

When I launch the repository Browser I see the following folders in my repository:

- Branches
- Tags
- trunk
- Trunk

However when I navigate into either **Trunk** or **trunk** they both lead to the same files (at the same revision). I don't know how this happened or how to clean it up without accidentally trashing my vital files.

Comment: Repository Urls are case sensitive - how you managed to end up with `trunk` and `Trunk` I'll have to leave to the real experts round here ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Filburt pointed out, SVN URLs are case sensitive.
Somebody (you?) has copied the 'Trunk' folder into the 'trunk' folder (or vice versa, but on the uppercase names of Branches and Tags I suggest the former).

How to fix:

- Examine how this trunk was created. Check the whole repository logs and filter by path "trunk"
- Make a diff between "trunk" and "Trunk". Make sure you have all files same version (this is easily done with TortoiseSVN Repo-Browser by using the "Mark for Comparsion"-Contextmenu), if not, either merge or just copy file contents from trunk to Trunk

If you are sure everything in trunk is also showing up on Trunk:

- switch all working copies from trunk to Trunk
- delete trunk